# How to repalce number in txt file R

Tags: r, numbers

How to replace number in text file R, replace 1 to 2?
example:

input:

```
1 2 0
1 2 0 
2 0 1
```

output:

```
2 2 0
2 2 0
2 0 2
```

Comment: *In a file?* Which of the following steps do you need help with? (1) reading the file into R, (2) replacing 1's with 2's, (3) writing the file out. What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have a text file and i want replace all number "1" with number "2".

Comment: you don't even need R for that if it's a txt file. Just open up a text editor, then CTRL + F, and replace all the 2's with 1

Comment: Yes. I understand that. If you want to do it with R, this has three steps. See my first comment for these steps. Can you do *any* of the steps? Have *tried* any of the steps? There are many resources for learning R in the [R tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info), I would suggest *An Introduction to R* as a good place to start.

Comment: YES, but i need it for a section in function in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code:

```
df <- read.table("something.txt", sep = ",",header = T)
df[df == 1] <- 2
```

Enjoy!!!

Comment: Great!!! Thank you.

Comment: you are welcome :)